# What does おなかの奥がきゅうううん mean here?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, conversations

Though I understood JP people say "きゅん/kyun" when they saw something cute or lovely on social medias, but what does おなかの奥がきゅうううん mean here?

I met this sentence in a visual novel, hope someone can explain its meaning to me.

A character said a girl is beautiful, and she felt too embarrassing after that.

> Girl「あ、あうう……っ、見ないでぇ、見ないでぇ。ゆうしゃさまにじっと見られるとぉ……っ。おなかの奥がきゅうううんってぇなっちゃううう」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

キュッ, ギュッ, キュー, キューン, キュン and so on are essentially onomatopoeias that express the feeling of "tightening" or "squeezing" such as those typically associated with angina, upset stomach and menstrual pain. When a young person says 胸がキュンと締め付けられる, it usually implies that they're in love, but if a middle-aged or older person says the same thing, you probably need to advise them to consult a physician. In your context, キュン refers to a certain sensation in women's lower abdominal organs when they are sexually aroused.